# Get the name of the active image in jQuery Light Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery Light Slider and it works fine. I want to access active element name. I try to print active image name in console but its not working.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
        gallery: true,
        item: 1,
        loop: true,
        slideMargin: 0,
        thumbItem: 9,
        onAfterSlide: function (el) {
            console.log(el);
        },
    });
});
```

This code gives...

```
jQuery.fn.init 
[ul#lightSlider.lightslider_left.slider_ul.lightSlider.lsGrab.lSSlide, 
context: document, selector: "#lightSlider", goToPrevSlide: ƒ, 
goToNextSlide: ƒ, mode: ƒ, …]
```

...in every slide change but I'm not suppose to get the name of the image.

I appreciate your ideas and helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your case this might help! (just use this console.log() instead of yours!

```
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
          gallery: true,
          item: 1,
          loop: true,
          slideMargin: 0,
          thumbItem: 9,
          onAfterSlide: function (el) {
              console.log($(el).find('.active img').attr('src')); 
          }, 
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate corrent active li's Image by following Jquery Code:

Try this:

```
$('#lightSlider').find(".active").find("img").attr("src");
```